# Dynamically Updating Widths of a CSS Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve created a simple horizontal bar graph just using CSS because I only need 3 bars. This graph shows 3 scores — the first two are dynamic and the last one is static.

My problem is that I can’t figure out an efficient way to change the widths of the bars based on their value. I have too many IF statements for each type of condition (i.e., if Score A is greater than Score B but Score A is less than Score C, etc.). How can I simplify this?

My code sample can be seen **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/uu9m1s3s/)**. Note: if the bar graphs don’t seem right, it is because the condition isn’t there for those type of scores. Please run the code again till all bars look horizontal.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="graph">
  <span id="score-a">Score A: </span>
  <span id="score-b">Score B: </span>
  <span id="score-c">Score C: 5</span>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var randomNumberA = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var randomNumberB = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
var staticScore = 5;

document.getElementById('score-a').innerHTML = "Score A: " + randomNumberA;
document.getElementById('score-b').innerHTML = "Score B: " + randomNumberB;

if (randomNumberA > randomNumberB && randomNumberA > staticScore) {
  $('#score-a').css({
    'width': "auto",
    'min-width': '100px'
  });
  $('#score-b').css({
    'width': "auto",
    'min-width': '122px'
  });
  $('#score-c').css({
    'width': "auto",
    'min-width': '112px'
  });
}

if (randomNumberA < randomNumberB && randomNumberA > staticScore) {
  $('#score-a').css({
    'width': "auto",
    'min-width': '100px'
  });
  $('#score-b').css({
    'width': "auto",
    'min-width': '122px'
  });
  $('#score-c').css({
    'width': "auto",
    'min-width': '112px'
  });
}
```

Comment: i am not sure if this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/uu9m1s3s/1/
why do you need `if` statements ?

Comment: @maddog Yes that works... thank you, but why the `vw` unit?

Comment: cool. `vw` is viewport width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lq664Ld/1/)

It calculates a width relative to the max score.

```
var maxScore = Math.max(randomNumberA, randomNumberB, staticScore);
var maxWidth = 130;

var widthA = (randomNumberA / maxScore) * maxWidth;
$('#score-a').css({
    'width': widthA + 'px'
});
var widthB = (randomNumberB / maxScore) * maxWidth;
$('#score-b').css({
    'width': widthB + 'px'
});
var widthC = (staticScore / maxScore) * maxWidth;
$('#score-c').css({
    'width': widthC + 'px'
});
```

I don't understand your usage of flexbox. It is what is causing your bars to line up next to each other. I modified your CSS so that this won't happen.

Comment: Thank you for this and fixing the CSS. But when the score is small (like 1 or 2), then sometimes the label is hard to see. The bar appears to be smaller than the label... probably due to `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: If you have scores of 10, 4, and 5, you may end up with both 4 and 5 hitting `min-width`, in which case they will be the same length but different scores. You could modify the js calculations to include a minWidth. ie. `var widthA = minWidth + (randomNumberA / maxScore) * (maxWidth - minWidth);`. The widths of your bars will not be directly proportional to your scores but they will at least be close.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vw` instead of `if` conditions. 
Please check this one:
jsfiddle.net/uu9m1s3s/1